# Why won't the scripts and stylesheets load over HTTP?

Tags: javascript, http

The following folder structure has been used to test. The `js` and `css` are in a directory above `pages` so that they can be included in all nested pages in the `pages` directory. When running the command `http-server` in the pages folder, the scripts and stylesheets are not found over HTTP.

Is there a better way to organize these files? The intention is to have the stylesheets and scripts in one place accessible to the all pages when testing over HTTP.

This project is using the [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) npm module.

**File structure**

```
.
+-- css
|   +-- styles.css
+-- js
|    +-- jquery.js
|    +-- popper.js
|    +-- bootstrap.js
+-- pages
|   +-- admin
|       +-- admin-page.html
|   +-- user
|       +-- user-page.html
|   +-- index.html
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />

    <title>Loading scripts and styles through HTTP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Voting to close this. You have not said why you expect them to reload (there is no mention of navigation or other events which would trigger this). You are asking two, unrelated questions. You have not explained why you think your code is not behaving as expected.

Comment: The [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command `http-server` in the `pages` folder, that folder becomes the webroot. You cannot access any files or folders outside of the webroot. So to be able to access the js and css files, you need to move them inside the pages folder. You can still use folders, of course.

Also make sure to change the paths in the html files, preferably using absolute paths from the webroot.

Note: there might be configuration options to allow you to access specific files or folders outside of the webroot, but I'm not aware of any in the `http-server` module.